# Was Achashveirosh feeling unwell in beginning of chapter six?

Tags: megillat-esther, choleh-sick, malchut-royalty, sleep

In the beginning of chapter six it says that the king couldn't sleep and he was told a story of how Mordechai saved him, etc. And it them says that Haman was coming to tell the king about his plan.

Question: Did the king happen to go to sleep extra early that night or what? Did he have a headache? I don't think Haman would come to wake up the King.

Comment: I believe that the Midrash explains that the king was suspicious that Haman was having an affair with Esther. His suspicion was especially aroused when Esther had requested just Haman to join the king and her at a party. As for the claim that you don't think that Haman would wake the king, think about this - Zeresh and all his friends told Haman to build the gallows, but said, "Go in the morning to tell the king about it." Haman doesn't even wait until the morning. Of course, protocol stated that he had to wait in the outer area until the king extended the scepter. Point is, Haman was waiting.

Comment: Also, the king's day starts whenever he happens to wake up and wants to see anyone. The people who want to speak to him would come as early as they could and wait for the king to call them in.

Comment: @DanF i think rashi mentions it that the king suspected haman was plotting with esther. Maybe he took it from the medrash, though. So it sounds like haman was so excited to hang mordechai he couldn't sleep and decided to wait all night in the king's court (?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the days of absolute monarchy, the king would start his day whenever he felt like. Those who wanted to get something from him would come as early as they could in order to be available whenever he called. Haman actually expected to have to wait until the king had gotten up, dressed, eaten and officially opened the court. Once the king woke up and had the records read to him, he did not think about how early it was or how inconvenient it might be to call in his advisors. He knew that someone was on duty at all times in case he wanted something (as was shown by having the royal records read to him).

[Esther 6:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16479/jewish/Chapter-6.htm/showrashi/true#v4)

> And the king said, "Who is in the court?" And Haman had come to the
>   outside court of the king's house, to petition the king to hang
>   Mordecai on the gallows that he had prepared for him.

Note that the king did not pay any attention to Haman and what he might want or what emergency might have arisen to bring him to the court. As soon as he entered the king started.

> And Haman entered, and the king said to him, "What should be done to a
>   man whom the king wishes to honor?" And Haman said to himself, "Whom
>   would the king wish to honor more than me?"